# What is the "Google Developers" app?

Tags: google-chrome, installation

This feels like a stupid question, but I can't find any information on it...

When you visit a `developers.google.com` URL (the Google Developers resource site) in Google Chrome browser, you have the option in the Omnibox to "Install Google Developers":

[image: Option to Install Google Developers]

Clicking it allows you to progress with the installation...

[image: Install Google Developers]

...but what is it?